# Exclude overlaid element from Google Maps viewport bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3 to create an inline map on a website. In its container element, I also have an absolute positioned overlay which shows some detail information, visually hovering over the map. Determining on context this element may grow up to the size of the entire map element.

All this is working fine, however the Maps instance of course still considers the overlaid part of the map a valid usable part of the map. This means that, especially if the overlay is at maximum height, `setCenter` doesn't focus on the *visible* center, and routes drawn with `DirectionsRenderer` are partially underneath the overlay.

See this image:
[image]

Is there a way to limit the *actual* viewport to the blueish area, so that `setCenter` centers on the arrow tip and `setBounds` fits to the blue part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have managed to implement an acceptably functional workaround for the time being.

Some general notes which are good to know:

- Every `Map` object has a `Projection`, which can convert between LatLng points to map points.
- The map points a `Projection` uses for calculation are in 'world' coordinates, meaning they are pixels on the world map at zoom level 0.
- Every zoom level exactly doubles the number of pixels shown. This means that the number of pixels in a given map point equals `2 ^ zoom`.

The samples below assume a 300px wide sidebar on the right - adapting to other borders should be easy.

### Centering

Using this knowledge, it becomes trivial to write a custom function for off-center centering:

```
function setCenter(latlng)
{
    var z = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
    var pnt = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng);
    map.setCenter(map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(
                    new google.maps.Point(pnt.x + 150/z, pnt.y)));
}
```

The crucial bits here are the `z` variable, and the `pnt.x + 150/z` calculation in the final line. Because of the above assumptions, this moves the point to center on 150 pixels to the left for the current zoom level, and as such compensates for the missing 300 pixels on the right sidebar.

### Bounding

The bounds issue is far less trivial. The reason for this is that to offset the points correctly, you need to know the zoom level. For recentering this doesn't change, but for fitting to previously unknown bounds it nearly always will. Since Google Maps uses unknown margins itself internally when fitting to bounds, there is no reliable way to predict the required zoom level.

Thus a possible solution is to invoke a two-step rocket. First off, call `fitBounds` with the entire map. This should make the bounds and zoom level at least *nearly* correct. Then right after that, do a second call to `fitBounds` corrected for the sidebar.

The following sample implementation should be called with a `LatLngBounds` object as parameter, or no parameters to default to the current bounds.

```
function setBounds(bnd, cb)
{
    var prj = map.getProjection();
    if(!bnd) bnd = map.getBounds();
    var ne = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(bnd.getNorthEast()),
        sw = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(bnd.getSouthWest());
    if(cb) ne.x += (300 / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom()));
    else google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'bounds_changed',
        function(){setBounds(bnd,1)});
    map.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        prj.fromPointToLatLng(sw), prj.fromPointToLatLng(ne)));
}
```

What we do here at first is get the actual points of the bounds, and since `cb` isn't set we install a once-only event on `bounds_changed`, which is then fired after the `fitBounds` is completed. This means that the function is automatically called a second time, after the zoom has been corrected. The second invocation, with `cb=1`, then offsets the box to correct for the 300 pixel wide sidebar.

In certain cases, this can lead to a slight off-animation, but in practice I've only seen this occur when really spamclicking on buttons causing a fit operation. It's running perfectly well otherwise.

Hope this helps someone  :)

Comment: Hey Niels, I'm solving identical problem and came across your solution. In the end, did it work for you? Have you found something better?

Comment: I implemented this on https://www.omines.nl/contact and it's still working fine today :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map [panBy() method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) which allows you to change the center of the map by a given distance in pixels.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but panning afterwards isn't a solution for fitting routes into a smaller area to begin with - it'll just scroll out the other end. I'm looking for a way to limit the viewport itself without stopping it from drawing in the excluded the area.

Comment: Right. I get your point. This question was asked already a few times here and never was answered with a viable solution. I would suggest to submit a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles) because I think it would be very useful to be able to manipulate the "viewport" size.

Comment: [Done](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6409)  :)   Also, I have managed to create viable workarounds which I'm testing right now.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what *viable workaround* you came up with.

Comment: Oh... Did I miss that? ;) I think I saw such a solution already. A working example would be a must!

Comment: Well I have a working example on our new company site, actually ripping it out to be standalone would be quite a job. I'll consider doing that this weekend  :P

Comment: I don't think Gmaps3 supports this. But I didn't understand: what is wrong with panning afterwards? Can't you just do a fitBounds to make sure the content you want to show is shown in your "visible" area, with the proper zoom level? Probably you need to do a custom fitBounds to ignore your right sidebar but still, that seems easy to do...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and ended up just forcing some "padding" to the east of a LatLngBounds object.

On the upside, it's simple and it works.  On the downside it's not really versatile.  Just a quick little hack.

```
// start with a standard LatLngBounds object, extending as you usually would...
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// ...

ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

// the multiplier used to add space; positive for east, negative for west
lngPadding = 1.5

extendedLng = ne.lng() + (ne.lng() - sw.lng()) * lngPadding;

// copy original and extend with the new Lng
extendedBounds = bounds;
extendedBounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), extendedLng));

map.fitBounds(extendedBounds);
```