# Geo-fence queries to google-maps

Tags: google-maps, parse-platform, geolocation

Is there a way with google-maps to save multiple geo-fenced areas which can then be queried based on a lat/long geo-point to return which of those fences contain the queried point? The reason for this is to set up an advertising portal for an app, which allows advertisers to choose their relevant geographical catchment area, in which they wish to advertise, and for which an app user can send their coordinates and receive a list of advertisers who have the user's point within their chosen catchment area. If not google-maps; does anyone know a provider offering such a service? My best approach to this as yet is to save a lat' min' and lat' max' and a long' min' and long' max' for each advertiser, against which to query, using a users location, but this obviously is limited to a rectangle rather than a polygon. I'm a bit stumped as to how to improve this. I am using Parse.com as my database which allows only 'distance to' as a query criteria and does not provide what I need in this respect, as such I am looking for another way to achieve this. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create such a geofence, you need to set the bounds on the Google map where a particular advertiser can add his/her advertisement.

The way to proceed with this is to write a method that can set the bounds on the Google Maps as per the locations you mentioned (lat' min' and lat' max' and a long' min' and long' max'). This will be a rectangle. A method that can take the coordinates as an array would be best fit in this case as you might have a geofence that is not a rectangle but a Polygon.

Call this method in the initialze() method where the code to add the marker is written. This will allow advertiser to add advertisement only in that region and not anywhere else.

To know more about the code, Please refer to this SO solution.
[Google maps marker only in a specific area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044600/google-maps-marker-only-in-a-specific-area)